# Did the Rebels know or suspect Vader himself would board the blockade runner?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, the-rebel-alliance

Episode IV begins with the Star Destroyer [*Devastator*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Devastator) (Vader's flagship at the time) pursuing the Rebel blockade runner [*Tantive IV*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tantive_IV). The blockade runner is soon captured and boarded by Imperial stormtroopers and Vader himself.

**Did the Rebels know or suspect Vader was on the Star Destroyer *before* he boarded the blockade runner? In other words, did they have any idea ahead of time that Vader would step through the breached door?**

[image]

I'm not suggesting that the Rebels should have surrendered rather than [stalled for time by resisting the Imperial boarding attempt](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/102801/31936). I'm just curious if they knew or suspected that they would have to resist Vader in addition to stormtroopers as the Imperials attempted to board the blockade runner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leia knew (and possibly the Tantive IV's command crew). It seems unlikely that rank and file soldiers would have been told.

> And Leia knew, the moment the ship identified itself as the Devastator, there would be no escape.
>
> **It was Darth Vader’s ship.**
>
> <sub><sup>[A New Hope: The Princess, the Scoundrel, and the Farm Boy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/A_New_Hope:_The_Princess,_the_Scoundrel,_and_the_Farm_Boy)</sup></sub>

Comment: but that doesn't she she *knew* he would be on the boarding party... however i will probably delete this comment after you give your full answer.

Comment: ...that was fast! +1. When did the ship identify itself as the *Devastator*? Before it captured the blockade runner (perhaps to tell it to surrender) or just before the stormtroopers actually boarded?

Comment: @Null - I'm assuming they identified themselves when they told the ship to hove to and prepare to be boarded.

Comment: @Skooba - She doesn't seem surprised to see him. Terrified, yes. Surprised, no.